# Why the windshield wipers move at deferent speed on captain and first officer?

Tags: landing, general-aviation

There is that feature linked to the pilot in command at the moment ?

Comment: Which airplane?

Answer (score 1):

If they are controlled automatically, then they might vary, although I would expect all wipers to run at the same speed. If they are activated manually and the speed is adjustable, or if each individual wipe is manually triggered, then the speed will depend on who is controlling them, and the captain and first officer might set them to different speeds if control is split between the two pilots.